# Generic parameter determining instance field type at execution

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Explanation of the situation:

I want to instanciate an object that can that have basically 2 parameters. A set of 'meta-parameters' and a value. The type of the value is determined by the 'meta-parameters'.

Example:

```
public class Meta
{

    public static final Meta META_FIRST = new Meta(String.class, new byte[] {0x00, 0x01});
    public static final Meta META_SECOND = new Meta(Float.class, new byte[] {0x00, 0x02});
    public static final Meta META_THIRD = new Meta(Double.class, new byte[] {0x00, 0x03});

    private Class<?> type;
    private byte[] prelude;

    private Meta(Class<?> type, byte[] prelude)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.prelude = prelude;
    }

    public Class<?> getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public byte[] getPrelude()
    {
        return this.prelude;
    }
}

public class Record
{
    private # value;
    private byte[] prelude;

    public Record(Meta meta, # value)
    {
        this.prelude = meta.getPrelude();
    }

    public void doSomeWork()
    {
        //Do some work with prelude and value
    }
}
```

Expected usage:

```
Record recordString = new Record(Meta.META_FIRST, "hello");
Record recordDouble = new Record(Meta.META_THIRD, 12.8);
```

My doubt yet is how to determine the type of 'value' (actually symbolized by '#').
I think generics or reflexion could solve my problem but I can't figure out how a parameter in the constructor can influence the type of another parameter.

I would like to avoid using the generic notation when instanciating a Record (that's the reason why I putted this 'generic' information in the Meta-class).

Can anyone has an idea how to solve that ? (feel free to suggest an other approach)

Note: it is also acceptable for me to initialize the record value later with a setter.

Comment: What will you do with the `Meta`- Class in `Record`?

Comment: I updated my question to provide more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have it compiling, you have to make the `Record` class generic (parameterized by the type of the value):

```
public class Record<T> {
    private T value;

    public Record(Meta meta, T value) {
        //Initialization
    }
}
```

**However**, I don't see a reason you have a `Meta` class, since it does nothing but holding the `Class` type of the `value`. In order to simplify the hierarchy and to make sure the `Meta` **is compatible** with the `value` type, I would remove the `Meta` class and keep a `Class<T>` in `Record`, which will represent the meta about the `value`.

```
public class Record<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> meta;

    public Record(T value, Class<T> meta) {
        //Initialization
    }

    public Class<T> getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }
}
```

and will use it like this:

```
Record recordString = new Record("hello", String.class);
Class<String> recordStringMeta = recordString.getMeta();
Record recordDouble = new Record(12.8, Double.class);
Class<Double> recordDoubleMeta = recordDouble.getMeta();
```

---

**Update**:

Since you don't want to have the `Record` class generic (which I don't advice you, but ...), you can introduce three constructors there and *copy* the passed `value` to an `Object` member. Unfortunately, this will force you to do casts when extracting the value back:

```
public class Record {
    private Object value;

    public Record(Meta meta, String value) {  ... }

    public Record(Meta meta, Double value) { ... }

    public Record(Meta meta, Float value) { ... }

}
```

Comment: I had simplified my example to make it simple by sadly it was hiding a part of the problematic. I updated my question to provide more informations (about the Meta-class).

Comment: I see. Then you can just stick to the first solution I provided (make the `Record` class generic).

Comment: Yep but I want to avoid the usage of the generics notation when creating a Record (sadly the users that will use the Record-class have no clue about generics...)

Comment: @Spotted, check out my latest update. It's not the solution I would advice you to go for, but since you want to avoid Generics, there's no better option

Comment: Huummm ok. So I guess the best solution is to teach my users to use generics... :-). Your latest update is problematic for me because the _type_ defined in a Meta-object and the (real) type of _value_ are not enforced to be the same (I am allowed to do `new Record(META_FIRST, 12.8);`), and therefore my method _doSomeWork_ will break at execution.